# Integrate SAML with SSO into the .net web application which has been using Forms authentication

Tags: c#, .net, single-sign-on, saml

I want to Integrate Single Sign on through SAML into my web application which is using Forms Authentication and membership. I really dont have an Idea on how to achieve this. any links or tutorials will be helpful. I would like to know where to start exactly and the various things i need to do to achieve this
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To work with SAML in .NET, you should use standard components. There are several commercial and open source options available.

I'm working on the [Kentor AuthServices](https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices) open source library. Using that library, you could migrate by:

1. Upgrade your application to use OWIN-based cookie-authentication and ASP.NET Identity instead of membership. This will increase security in general.
2. Configure the Kentor AuthServices SAML2 Owin middleware to be used as an external authentication provider with ASP.NET Identity.

To get started, it's probably easiest to create a new empty ASP.NET application where all code is generated for you. Then you can copy that code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Componet Pro SAML](http://www.componentpro.com/doc/saml/AtAGlance.htm)
Componet Pro SAML can be used from ASP.NET web pages, Windows Forms and Web Services and runs under .NET Framework 2.x and above.

Componet Pro SAML supports [Single Sign (SSO) scenario](http://www.componentpro.com/doc/saml/SP-Initiated-Web-Applications.htm)